# Merging an array while grouping from MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping

I have a collection that looks something like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e2",
        "productId": 1,
        "stock": 10,
        "unit": "item",
        "price": 20,
        "images": [
            "http://productimages.com/1/001.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/1/002.jpg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e3",
        "productId": 1,
        "stock": 20,
        "unit": "item",
        "price": 30,
        "images": [
            "http://productimages.com/1/003.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/1/004.jpg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e4",
        "productId": 2,
        "stock": 5,
        "unit": "item",
        "price": 15,
        "images": [
            "http://productimages.com/2/001.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/2/002.jpg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e5",
        "productId": 2,
        "stock": 5,
        "unit": "item",
        "price": 12,
        "images": [
            "http://productimages.com/2/003.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/2/004.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
```

And I aggregate it as follows:

```js
db.variants.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$productId",
            "price": { "$min": "$price" },
            "stock": { "$sum": "$stock" },
            "unit": { "$first": "$unit" },
            "images": { "$push": "$images" },
            "variants": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

which produces the following output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "price": 12,
        "stock": 10,
        "unit": "item",
        "images": [
            [
                "http://productimages.com/2/001.jpg",
                "http://productimages.com/2/002.jpg"
            ],
            [
                "http://productimages.com/2/003.jpg",
                "http://productimages.com/2/004.jpg"
            ]
        ],
        "variants": [
            {
                "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e4",
                "productId": 2,
                "stock": 5,
                "unit": "item",
                "price": 15,
                "images": [
                    "http://productimages.com/2/001.jpg",
                    "http://productimages.com/2/002.jpg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e5",
                "productId": 2,
                "stock": 5,
                "unit": "item",
                "price": 12,
                "images": [
                    "http://productimages.com/2/003.jpg",
                    "http://productimages.com/2/004.jpg"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "price": 20,
        "stock": 30,
        "unit": "item",
        "images": [
            [
                "http://productimages.com/1/001.jpg",
                "http://productimages.com/1/002.jpg"
            ],
            [
                "http://productimages.com/1/003.jpg",
                "http://productimages.com/1/004.jpg"
            ]
        ],
        "variants": [
            {
                "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e2",
                "productId": 1,
                "stock": 10,
                "unit": "item",
                "price": 20,
                "images": [
                    "http://productimages.com/1/001.jpg",
                    "http://productimages.com/1/002.jpg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e3",
                "productId": 1,
                "stock": 20,
                "unit": "item",
                "price": 30,
                "images": [
                    "http://productimages.com/1/003.jpg",
                    "http://productimages.com/1/004.jpg"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

however I would like to get

```
[
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "price": 12,
        "stock": 10,
        "unit": "item",
        "images": [
            "http://productimages.com/2/001.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/2/002.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/2/003.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/2/004.jpg"
        ],
        "variants": [
            {
                "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e4",
                "productId": 2,
                "stock": 5,
                "unit": "item",
                "price": 15,
                "images": [
                    "http://productimages.com/2/001.jpg",
                    "http://productimages.com/2/002.jpg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e5",
                "productId": 2,
                "stock": 5,
                "unit": "item",
                "price": 12,
                "images": [
                    "http://productimages.com/2/003.jpg",
                    "http://productimages.com/2/004.jpg"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "price": 20,
        "stock": 30,
        "unit": "item",
        "images": [
            "http://productimages.com/1/001.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/1/002.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/1/003.jpg",
            "http://productimages.com/1/004.jpg"
        ],
        "variants": [
            {
                "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e2",
                "productId": 1,
                "stock": 10,
                "unit": "item",
                "price": 20,
                "images": [
                    "http://productimages.com/1/001.jpg",
                    "http://productimages.com/1/002.jpg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f0307520ac9361c0d7088e3",
                "productId": 1,
                "stock": 20,
                "unit": "item",
                "price": 30,
                "images": [
                    "http://productimages.com/1/003.jpg",
                    "http://productimages.com/1/004.jpg"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

instead. I have tried replacing the `images` expression with `images.*` but this produced an empty set.

I have also tried adding a `$reduce` projection to the pipeline as shown at [combine array fields into a single array field mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638861/combine-array-fields-into-a-single-array-field-mongo/50639097#50639097):

```js
db.variants.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$productId",
            "price": { "$min": "$price" },
            "stock": { "$sum": "$stock" },
            "unit": { "$first": "$unit" },
            "images": { "$push": "$images" },
            "variants": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "images": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": { "$concatArrays": ["images.*"] },
                    "initialValue": [],
                    "in": { "$setUnion": ["$$this", "$$value"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

which fails with:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: $concatArrays only supports arrays, not string",
    "code" : 28664,
    "codeName" : "Location28664"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638861/combine-array-fields-into-a-single-array-field-mongo/50639097#50639097 ?

Comment: @mickl Sort of. It seems to be it's own aggregation rule, I'm not sure how I would use it inside a group aggregation. Would it have to be it's own step in the pipeline? I think an answer to this specific question might be more helpful to me and to others than just a link to that question.

Comment: Yes, you just need to add additional step after `$group` to flatten your array of arrays, just like in that example

Comment: @mickl I've tried that, but I get an error. This seems to be working with named arrays, whereas I have an array of arrays comming in from my group

Comment: Try: `input: "$images"`, there's no syntax with asterisk

Comment: @mickl ok that works but only if I add all the props from the grouping into the projection. Are you sure there isn't a less verbose way? Plugging the `$reduce` object directly into the group step only produces an error for $$this.

Comment: Every pipeline stage gets single document as input. When you run `$group` the input is an array whereas you need an array of arrays when you're applying `$reduce` thus it has to be a separate step (once the data is aggregated as an array of arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) together with [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/).

Instead of `$project` you can use `$addFields`, available from MongoDB v3.4 or `$set` available from v4.2 to keep other fields

```
db.variants.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$productId",
      "price": {
        "$min": "$price"
      },
      "stock": {
        "$sum": "$stock"
      },
      "unit": {
        "$first": "$unit"
      },
      "images": {
        "$push": "$images"
      },
      "variants": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": { // or $set
      "images": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$images",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```